# How did Kiri get this super power?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar: The Way of Water* (2022), Kiri controls aquatic plants to attack the Sky People:

[image]

How did Kiri get this super power?

Comment: https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Tsaheylu - We see natives using their 'queue' to control a wide array of creatures;

Comment: One theory is that Kiri is an avatar of Eywa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know.

James Cameron is heavily drawing from religious mythology here on Earth, including Christian mythology. Kiri is the daughter of Dr. Grace Augustine's avatar. However, we know nothing about her father, and it is heavily implied that she *has none*, i.e., that Dr. Grace's avatar miraculously became pregnant. (Sound familiar?)

Epileptic seizures have also for a long time in many Earth cultures been interpreted as being caused by having a connection to a supernatural being that overwhelmes the brain.

So, one theory is that, because of Dr. Grace's dedication to Eywa, it was Eywa herself who chose to impregnate Dr. Grace's avatar. In other words, Kiri is an offspring or an avatar of Eywa herself.

Comment: Sounds incredibly familiar, the exact same thing happened to a woman I was dating — but did the Child Support Agency want to hear that? _Noooooooooooo_